# 'Event' on cancel UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView

Tags: ios7, uitableview

Let's say that we have a `UITableView` in edit mode.

User has tap the minus sign and the `DeleteConfirmationView` appeared. Now user does not tap on `DeleteConfirmationView` but outside it, so the `DeleteConfirmationView` disappear.

Is there an event/callback/message (whatever is called) that help me know that user didn't tap on (cancel) `DeleteConfirmationView`?